# Does ioctl FIONREAD on a socket block operations on other sockets while it is running?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

In my performance tests, running many FIONREADs in parallel on different sockets, seemed to slow each other down. (As if there was contention for a global networking lock.) This this expected?